# How to open new window if a mouse wheel is clicked on imagebutton? (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, click, imagebutton

i have an imagebutton in my page. If i click it with left mouse button, page is redirected, but if i click it with middle button, than i am able to scroll the page by moving mouse. I would like to have the redirect function for middle mouse click like it is for left button click. Any suggestions? Thanks, Jim

Comment: Middle button ? do you mean `Scroll Wheel` ?

Comment: I think using the middle mouse button for opening a link in a new tab is a common browser feature and not something that is to be achieved using your code.

Comment: srinivas, dont know why, but its not working for my page in opera/firefox/explorer. is it possible because its on asp.net developement server than?

Comment: Take a look at the MouseWheel event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousewheel.aspx